# Qual è il significato di "spaccato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Le conchiglie e il tempo* di Italo Calvino ho letto:

> Lo **spaccato** della crosta terrestre ha dovuto far riaffiorare i nostri gusci abbandonati cento trecento cinquecento milioni d'anni prima, perché la dimensione verticale del tempo si aprisse a voi e vi liberasse dal giro sempre ripetuto della ruota degli astri in cui continuavate a incasellare il corso del vostro esistere frammentario.

Con "i nostri gusci abbandonati cento trecento cinquecento milioni d'anni prima" l'autore si riferisce alle conchiglie calcaree prodotte più di cento milioni d'anni fa che si sono conservate come fossili negli strati geologici. Non capisco bene il significato di "spaccato della crosta terrestre" nel brano precedente. È chiaro che "spaccato" ha qui la funzione di sostantivo. Ho letto tutte le [accezioni di "spaccato" come sostantivo del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spaccato/)
e quella che mi è sembrata più coerente col testo è

> In geologia, *s. geologico*, lo stesso che *profilo geologico*.

Ho cercato il significato di "profilo geologico" e nel [dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/profilo-geologico) ho trovato

> geol. rappresentazione di una sezione verticale del terreno che riporta la struttura e la successione degli strati e delle formazioni rocciose.

Tuttavia, nel testo di Calvino, "spaccato della crosta terrestre" non sembra essere una rappresentazione del terreno, ma qualcosa che è accaduto veramente nella crosta terrestre per far venir fuori i fossili delle conchiglie. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "spaccato della crosta terrestre" in questo contesto?

Comment: Dopo averci pensato per un po' l'unica cosa che mi viene in mente è che Calvino abbia frainteso cos'è uno spaccato geologico (o magari che si tratti di un errore lasciato da varie revisioni del testo). Spero che qualcuno riesca a dare una risposta più soddisfacente

Answer (score 4):

Credo che qui Calvino usi correttamente il termine "spaccato", e proprio nel senso di "profilo" (geologico). Lo dimostra anche il riferimento alla "dimensione verticale del tempo" (che libera dalla ciclicità).
Se si fa uno spaccato geologico si possono osservare i vari strati delle rocce; ogni strato rappresenta un'epoca ("cento, trecento, cinquecento" milioni di anni fa). Guardando lo spaccato, dunque, il tempo appare come lineare (le epoche si susseguono, sempre diverse) e non come circolare (con le stesse cose che tornano a ripetersi).

Comment: Il mio problema per accettare questa spiegazione è che, secondo il dizionario, il "profilo geologico" è una rappresentazione del terreno, però nel testo di Calvino si legge "lo spaccato della crosta terrestre ha dovuto far riaffiorare i nostri gusci...". Non sembra che una rappresentazione della crosta terrestre possa far riaffiorare i gusci delle conchiglie, ma qualche fenomeno che produca una frattura della crosta terrestre.

Comment: @Charo La spiegazione di Benedetta è quella che avrei fornito anch'io, facendo leva proprio sull'espressione "dimensione verticale del tempo", che suggerisce l'idea di una sovrapposizione di ere geologiche, e quindi di strati, scandita dal trascorrere del tempo. Credo che il verbo "riaffiorare" sia utilizzato in [senso figurato](http://is.gd/jqDs2J), non come sinonimo di "emergere" ma nell'accezione di "[far] ritornare alla memoria": quei gusci nascosti sarebbero rimasti ancora una volta nell'oblio (essendo nascosti alla vista), se lo *spaccato* della crosta terrestre non li avesse rivelati.