# "Qualcosa che è accaduto" oppure "qualcosa che è accaduta"?

Tags: word-choice, gender, agreement

Quando ho scritto [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/6814/707) ho messo "qualcosa che è accaduto veramente nella crosta terrestre", ma poi mi è venuto il dubbio se dovessi scrivere "qualcosa che è accaduta" tenendo conto che "cosa" è femminile. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Qualcosa* non è femminile (nonostante *cosa* lo sia), ma neutro e viene usualmente concordato al maschile. Per citare il [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/qualcosa/)

> Indica in modo indeterminato una o alcune cose e può essere sostituito dalla locuz. qualche cosa, dalla quale deriva; ha valore neutro e concorda per lo più come masch.

Vedi anche ad esempio l'espressione *qualcos'altro* (e non *qualcos'altra*).

Quindi la forma giusta è

> Qualcosa che è accaduto.

Comment: Funny enough, `(una) cosa` è femminile,  `(una) qualche cosa` è ovviamente femminile, ma la combinazione `(un) qualcosa` è maschile.